# Unable to create cookie if it has a domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

My controller has the following code

```
cookies[:book] = { :value => "Kids Puzzles", :expires => 2.years.from_now, :domain => "foo.com" }
```

Unable to create cookie if it has a domain which is different than the server in which the application is running. How should I create/delete a cookie in such cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that.

You can set a cookie for example.com within an app running at app.example.com but not for foo.com.